# variable value not updated after recursive call

Tags: java

In one of my methods I'm writing a try catch to validate the user's input. If the user enters the wrong data type the method is called again and they are prompted to re-enter. For some reason when the method is called for the second time no matter what the value entered is, it will always return as 0.

```
public static int enterNumGadgets(){   

    int numOfGadgetsIn = 0;

    try{
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of items you wish to insure.");
        numOfGadgetsIn = EasyScanner.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException exception){

        System.out.println("You must enter a number.");
        EasyScanner.nextLine(); //consume new line left over
        enterNumGadgets(); //call the method again

    }
    return numOfGadgetsIn;
}
```

---

Output with correct data type the first time the method is called:

Name: test

Reference Number: te123s

Number of Gadgets: 1

Most expensive item:1.0

---

Output with incorrect data type on first call, but correct data type on second:

Name: test

Reference Number: te123s

Number of Gadgets: 0

Most expensive item:1.0

---

Notice how it seems that after the second call to enterNumGadgets() it seems to ignore the new value int numOfGadgetsIn is set to in try{...} and returns it as 0.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Where do you set `numOfGadgetsIn`?

Comment: Your recursive case needs to assign the result of the recursive call to `enterNumGadgets()` to `numOfGadgetsIn`

Comment: Each method invocation has its own "version" of the variable. You need to either store the variable's result in a shared field, or return it from the method and have the recursive call take that value and do something with it. The latter is the more common approach -- for instance, the recursive call of a Fibonacci method is `return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)`. Note that this take each call's return value, combines them, and then returns that combined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a second rekursiv call (where your user data is valid), your data is not assigned to a new variable. instead the variable on your first call (where user data is invalid) is used, which is still 0.

This should work:

```
public static int enterNumGadgets(){   

int numOfGadgetsIn = 0;

try{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of items you wish to insure.");
    numOfGadgetsIn = EasyScanner.nextInt();
}
catch(InputMismatchException exception){

    System.out.println("You must enter a number.");
    EasyScanner.nextLine(); //consume new line left over
    numOfGadgetsIn = enterNumGadgets(); //call the method again

}
return numOfGadgetsIn;
```

}

Comment: with the line ´numOfGadgetsIn = enterNumGadgets();´ in the "catch" part. It will only call itself again if ´EasyScanner´ throws an Exception. In that case ´numOfGadgetsIn´ is still 0 and you call the method again. If you have now a valid user-input, the methode returns the correkt number to your first call (where the data was invalid). There you take the return value and overwrite ´numOfGadgetsIn´.